# "Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : 'match' requires vector arguments"

Tags: r, match, stop-words

I have this code chunk to get a count of the words in a training data set, index it by in which article number it is found.
Here is the dataframe I'm working with and once the code runs, each word in the document column will be placed in cell of its own and indexed to which Document  it came from (numbers in the far left column.

```
dput(droplevels(head(TrainData)))
structure(list(Class = c("atheism", "atheism", "atheism", "atheism", 
"atheism", "atheism"), Document = c(" atheism faq atheist resources ", 
" atheism faq introduction to atheism archive name atheism introduction ",
"gospel dating in article mimsy umd edu mangoe cs umd edu charley ", 
"university violating separation of church state dmn kepler unh edu ",  
"soc motss et al princeton axes matching funds for boy scouts in article ",   
"a visit from the jehovah s witnesses in article apr batman bmd trw com"  
), Index = 1:6), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

The code chunk to separate each word and index it is:

```
library(tidytext) 
TrainData$Index = 1:dim(TrainData)[1]  # provides an index of what articles are connected with each word
TrainData_words <- TrainData %>%     # add the original row numbers as index
  unnest_tokens(word,Document) %>%
  filter(str_detect(word, "[a-z']$"),
     !word %in% stop_words$word)   # removing the stop-words (actual words that do not impact text mining or correlation)
```

It ran fine and now I get the following error:
"Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) :  'match' requires vector arguments"

Running the traceback() produces:

```
> traceback()
12: word %in% stop_words$word
11: match.arg(method)
10: filter(., str_detect(word, "[a-z']$"), !word %in% stop_words$word)
9: filter(., str_detect(word, "[a-z']$"), !word %in% stop_words$word)
8: function_list[[k]](value)
7: withVisible(function_list[[k]](value))
6: freduce(value, `_function_list`)
5: `_fseq`(`_lhs`)
4: eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
3: eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
2: withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env))
1: TrainData %>% unnest_tokens(word, Document) %>% filter(str_detect(word, 
       "[a-z']$"), !word %in% stop_words$word)
```

I have read through the postings on this particular error message, a=but still cannot figure what may have changed or omitted?
Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Can you provide some data to make your example reproducible? Something like `dput(head(TrainData))` is probably good.

Comment: the stand alone index belonged to the comment on the prior line--now fixed.  I tried to place a semblance of the dataframe I am working with and I hope it comes across OK.  It has four columns, from L-R: row number (document number), Class, Document, Index.  Thank you.

Comment: Gregor, you are incredibly helpful and supportive, I appreciate it!  I will try the new code you offered and see what I can do...stay tuned! Thank you.

Comment: Hope the new dataframe sample format works.

Comment: It does... perhaps too well. When I call the data you provide `TrainingData` and run your `unnest_tokens() %>% filter()` on it, it works perfectly, not errors, stop words removed. Can you confirm the same on that data sample?

Comment: No, I still get the same error, right at the beginning of this line TrainData_words <-  TrainData %>%...

Comment: Try again in a fresh R session. Restart R, load the packages, use the `dput()` data from the question, and see. If it persists, run `traceback()` after the error and post the result in the question as well.

Comment: I  wonder if it has something to do with updating some R packages that it stopped working?

Comment: I'm on R 3.5.2, with `dplyr` 0.8.0.1, `stringr` 1.3.1, `tidytext` 0.2.0, and `stopwords` 0.9.0. If your versions are older than that you could try updating.

Comment: I had the same ones exactly, except stringr was 1.4.0 and I rolled it back to 1.3.1, still to no avail.

Comment: I also reloaded both R and RStudio and still get the same error.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't reproduce. When I run the code in your question on the data on your question, it works just fine.

Comment: OK, thank you for your time and assistance.

Comment: @Shawn hi shawn, came across this post after I was running into the same error. While I can't figure out precisely what's causing the bug, I was able to get my code working again. Try to add parenthesis around the second boolean statement in your filter call to separate your negation exclamation. So `filter(str_detect(word, "[a-z']$"),
     !word %in% stop_words$word)` would become `filter(str_detect(word, "[a-z']$"),
     !(word %in% stop_words$word))`

Comment: @icj, thank you very much for your follow up.  I think I figured it out and it worked well for my codes and results.  I do appreciate your time and offering good advice.  Be well.